# Variadic template argument deduction - strange error and segfault in recent clang

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, clang++

The following code-snipped produces an error message and a subsequent segfault with both clang 5.0.0 and the current [master](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/7a6944054dfa28e77dc0b930f23ab967de13e527) branch. It compiles fine with any c++11 compliant g++.

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename... T> struct B {};
template <typename T> struct gf {};
template <typename... A> B<A...> make_B(std::initializer_list<gf<A...>> const &V) { return {}; }

int main() {
  auto x = gf<int>{};
  auto b = make_B<int>({x, x, x}); // clang segfault
  //auto b = make_B({x, x, x}); // ok
}
```

The error message reads

```
test.cpp:5:26: error: too many template arguments for class template 'gf'
template <typename... A> B<A...> make_B(std::initializer_list<gf<A...>> const &V) { return {}; }
                                               ^
test.cpp:9:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_B<int>' 
requested here
  auto b = make_B<int>({x, x, x}); // clang crash
                  ^
test.cpp:4:30: note: template is declared here
template <typename T> struct gf {};
```

- Why does clang report an error here? The number of template arguments deduced for `gf` in the call to `make_B<int>` should be one.
- Regarding the segfault following the error message I have now filed a [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34685)

Comment: [Compiles here with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e466161c767ebacd)

Comment: [Can reproduce here](https://godbolt.org/g/GCCzZ7).

Comment: @nwp Could it be a libc++ vs libstdc++ issue?